# (parser) syntax error on "array: .word 2,5,3,7,9,(some random numbers)"

Tags: mips

I´m writing a MIPS code trying to find a random given number on my array(vector).
I have a problem when i try to assemble it in QtSpim but it declare an error "spin:(parser)syntax error.....                                     vector:                    .word 2,3,5,6,8,1,3,2,5,9"

```
    size = 4        
    N = 10          
                            .data

             vector:                    .word   2,3,5,6,8,1,3,2,5,9
             Tofind:                    .word   6      
             Finded:                    .word   0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ironically, I just tripped over this yesterday in my own code. I normally use `mars` instead of `spim`, but used `spim`. `mars` will accept this just fine, but `spim` doesn't like it.

Change:

```
vector:                    .word   2,3,5,6,8,1,3,2,5,9
```

Into:

```
vector:                    .word   2 3 5 6 8 1 3 2 5 9
```

Comment: Thank You very much it worked, it seems like it doesn't  like the comas without spaces. Thanks.

Comment: Just ran into this, QtSpim also accepted "2, 3, 5, 6, 8..." (numbers with spaces after comma)